# react-native map array remove duplicates & order

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm mapping a json array and I'd like to remove duplicates and alphabetically order the results by key1.

```
array: [{key1:'hello',key2:'goodbye'},{key1:'hello',key2:'goodbye'},{key1:'bonjour',key2:'adios'}]

this.state.array.map((item,index) => (

<Text key={index}>{item.key1} {item.key2}</Text>

))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lodash` for collection manipulation.

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const arr = [{key1:'hello',key2:'goodbye'},
{key1:'hello',key2:'goodbye'},{key1:'bonjour',key2:'adios'}]

const val = 
    _.chain(arr)
        .uniqWith(_.isEqual)
        .sortBy("key1")
        .value()

console.log(val)
```

See working example: https://repl.it/repls/AuthorizedPerfumedFiletype